# vue js two SPAs

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I am building a web app with two layouts (for login page, and dashboard). Each of them are represented as SPA application, so each has router-view. The main problem is 'How to connect them and redirect from one to another?'.

I have a App.vue - check if user is authorized. if yes - redirect to Dashboard.vue, else - redirect to Login.vue. Each of them has there own router-view.

Comment: Why are you separating them out? You should just use a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to check the authentication status of the user and redirect appropriately.

Comment: @craig_h my auth page consist of Base.vue (Layout), Login.vue and Restore.vue. When user is not authorized App.vue redirect to Base.vue, there we check where we are (/login or /restore) and depend on it we import component we need. Is it correct way or i should change my project structure ? My dashboard has same structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SPA should be a single html file which serves up your app and all the routes, so the basic structure should be:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">

</div>

<!-- bundled file -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue' 
import VueRouter from 'vue-router' 

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './components/App.vue' // import Base component

// Import views to register with vue-router
import Login from './components/views/Login.vue'
import Dashboard from './components/views/Dashboard.vue'

const guard = function(to, from, next) {
    // Check if user is logged in (you will need to write that logic)
    if (userIsLoggedIn) {
        next();
    } else {
        router.push('/login');
    }
};

const routes = [{
      path: '/login',
        component: Login
      },{
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            guard(to, from, next); // Guard this route
      }
}]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history', // history mode 
    routes
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App) // mount base component
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Your layout -->

    <!-- All views get served up here -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>  
</template>
```

I haven't tested that, but in this scenario every view component gets served up by `App.vue` which is mounted on the main vue instance. You then use the `beforeEach` guard to check that the user is logged in, if they are then you call `next()` which takes them to the route, if they are not then you redirect them to login.

Comment: i knew that, thx, the problem is that login page consist of two pages (login and restore) like that ->
path: 'auth',
component: Base,
children: [
{ path: 'login', component: Login },
{ path: 'restore', component: Restore }]

path: 'dashboard',
component: Base,
children: [
{ path: 'schedule', component: Schedule },
{ path: 'Settings', component: Settings }] and so on

Comment: It's not exactly clear why you are doing that, could you post some code to show what you are actually doing?

Comment: Oh OK, that's not another SPA that's [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html) you just use `router.push` to push to the relevant route, it's no different, `Base` will still be served up by your top level `router-view`

Comment: yeah, exactly. So the problem is when i am using router.push in Login.vue to /dashboard, its still use Base.vue of Auth

Comment: I think you should just be using a guard to redirect to `login` or `restore` which should be top level routes, rather than trying to nest those routes in a component that does the authentication, there's no need for that, especially if the component is not providing a layout. I tend to think as nested routes as good for things like tabs, not authenticating and redirecting users.

Comment: Base.vue is a layout for Login.vue and Restore.vue, is there another way to implement Base.vue as layout?

Comment: It depends how complex it is, but you might just be able to use a [slot](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) instead.

Answer (score -1):

`vue-router` has the ability to create custom guards for any route. You do not need 2 separate applications, just some safety with the routes in your router.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Your guard could be a function that checks for authentication.

Here's a full implementation tutorial from Auth0: https://auth0.com/blog/vuejs2-authentication-tutorial/

Comment: The first link is dead.